# When trying to write multiple bytes to a serial port, all 0x00s are skipped

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I am using a dynamixel XL320 servo, and am trying to control it using an Arduino Uno. I’m trying to send a simple packet that turns on an LED. I believe the correct format of this packet according to the dynamixel documentation is the following: FF FF FD 00 01 09 00 03 19 00 01 00 00 00 3F 1D (However, the correctness of this packet at the moment is ultimately unimportant to my problem). Before actually writing any more of my servo library, I decided to try to just send an array using Serial.write, to ensure that would transmit properly. I used puTTY session logging, and then a hex editor to track what was actually sent. The results are: 
FF FF FD 01 09 03 19 01 3F 1D.

I’ve seen other issues where 0x00 is interpreted as null in a string and so a string like 0x10, 0x00, 0xDD would only send 0x10. But here as an array that shouldn’t be a problem. Here, it seems like the 00’s are just being skipped. Would really appreciate help here, and please let me know if more clarity is needed this is first time posting here.

My code for this test is as simple as I could think to make it:

````
Serial.begin(9600);
while(!Serial) {;} 
uint8_t data[16]= {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFD, 0x00, 0x01, 0x09, 0x00, 0x03, 0x19, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x1D};
Serial.write(data, sizeof(data));```
````

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure PuTTY is not messing up with your bytes?

Comment: I would certainly second Edgar's sentiment. The biggest suspect is your receiving setup, not the Arduino.

Comment: I’m not sure, that could be true. How did either of you set up the receiving end?